# Send TLS shutdown as a client with openssl commandline

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am using `openssl` commandline as a client to communicate with a server that uses TLS like so:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:xxxx
```

I want the client to send  TLS shutdown to the server with the command line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

A TLS shutdown is send on TLS connection close. There is no way supported in s_client to explicitly trigger a SSL_shutdown but keep the underlying TCP connection open.

A close can for example be triggered by entering "Q" on the input, see [CONNECTED COMMANDS](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-s_client.html#CONNECTED-COMMANDS) in the documentation. See also the comment from dave_thompson_085 for other ways how a close can be triggered.

Comment: `s_client` **also** does shutdown-and-close **when it gets EOF on standard input** _unless_ you specify `-ign_eof`. If you don't redirect e.g. with `<` or `|` it has the same stdin as the shell (or CMD/PS) that runs it, which in turn is usually but not always the user's terminal or console, in which case on Unix a line 'consisting' of ctrl-D is usually EOF and on Windows (except Unix-on-Windows emulations like cygwin) ctrl-Z always(?) is. If you `</dev/null` on Unix or `<NUL` on Windows it gets EOF immediately.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Thanks for mentioning these all additional methods to reach a full connection close, which also includes a SSL shutdown. But there is still no way to force a  SSL shutdown without also closing the underlying TCP connection.